# Not able to pass a string array to an xslt and generate an html file

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, xslt

I am creating an XsltArgumentList in which I am a string array, columnNameList, using this string array I am verifying the columnNames and printing column header accordingly. Code is following

C# code:

```
XsltArgumentList xsltArgumentList = new XsltArgumentList();
string[] columnList = new string[] { "TranNo", "DueDate", "TranType" };

XPathNavigator[] navigators =
                columnList.Select(s => new XElement("column", s).CreateNavigator()).ToArray();

xsltArgumentList.AddParam("columnList", string.Empty, navigators);
```

Xslt code:

```
<xsl:param name="columnList"/>

<tr>
<xsl:for-each select="columnList/column">                       
    <xsl:if test="contains('TranNo', .)">
        <th>Transaction #</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('DueDate', .)">
        <th>Due Date</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('TranDate', .)">
        <th>Date</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('TranType', .)">
        <th>Type</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('PONumber', .)">
        <th>PO #</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('PRONumber', .)">
        <th>PRO #</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('BOLNumber', .)">
        <th>BOL #</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('ReferenceNo', .)">
        <th>REF #</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('Charge', .)">
        <th>Invoice Amount</th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains('OpenAmount', .)">
        <th>Open Amount</th>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

but its not printing any column.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can pass in an `XPathNavigator[]` to be treated as a node set in XSLT but you need to make sure you use the same parameter name in C# and in XSLT and you need to be aware that you don't need the `column` in the path as you already pass in a node set with those elements. Add to that the fix already suggested you get

```
    XsltArgumentList xsltArgumentList = new XsltArgumentList();
    string[] columnList = new string[] { "TranNo", "DueDate", "TranType" };

    XPathNavigator[] navigators =
                    columnList.Select(s => new XElement("column", s).CreateNavigator()).ToArray();

    xsltArgumentList.AddParam("columnList", "", navigators);
```

in C# and `<xsl:param name="columnList"/>` and `<xsl:for-each select="$columnList">` in XSLT.

Comment: but columns displayed in random order

Comment: This was very helpful. The only thing missing in this example is what's needed inside of your <xsl:for-each.. loop to render each string's value.  <xsl:value-of select="."/>

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

```
<xsl:for-each select="columnList/column">
```

looks for an element named `columnList` in the input XML. If you want to reference a parameter, you need to use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$columnList/column">
```

Second problem: the parameter is a string; it has no nodes.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k I am not able to understand your the second point.. can u please explain? I am new to this..